# how to use redux-persist-transform-filter correctly

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I am trying to persist only one variable (which is an array with arrays and objects inside) from my galleryReducer. I have 3 total reducers, cameraReducer, signupReducer, galleryReducer. Right now I am persisting the entire galleryReducer, but I am not sure how to configure the createFilter from'redux-persist-transform-filter'to only persist the failedUploads.  Here is the code of the setup to make sense of this all:

**Here is what my galleryReducer looks like:**

```
const initialState = {
    galleries: {
        galleries: [
            {
                loading: true,
            },
        ],
        error: false,
    },
     ...
    failedUploads: [ <--- THE PORTION OF THIS REDUCER THAT I WANT TO PERSIST.
        {
            userID: '',
            failedUploads: [],
        },
    ],
  
}
```

**The set up in my app.js**

```
    import signupReducer from './src/store/signup-auth/reducer'
    import cameraReducer from './src/store/camera/reducer'
    import galleryReducer from './src/store/event/reducer'
    
    const persistConfig = {
        key: 'root',
        storage: AsyncStorage,
        whitelist: ['galleryReducer'],
    }
    
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        signupReducer: signupReducer,
        cameraReducer: cameraReducer,
        galleryReducer: galleryReducer,
    })
    
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
    
    const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
    
    const persistor = persistStore(store)
    
    return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate
                    loading={<LoadingViewWithoutInsets />}
                    persistor={persistor}
                >
                    <AppNavigator />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
    
           )
```

Comment: Hi my friend, is the problem has been solved?

Comment: Hi Nima,

Yes, thank you for the help. 
I just want to mention that I switched my entire app from Redux to Zustand. It is miles better than Redux. It is so simple, does not wrap your app in any providers, there is no dispatch or middle wear needed for async functions or any middle wear for persisting. I highly recommend it.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, I'll check the `Zustand`. Good Luck